# How to prevent function call on page refresh in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm calling controller function with get request:

```
Route::get('/add/{id}', ['as'=>'addProduct','uses'=>'CartController@addProduct']);
```

This is my addProduct function :

```
public function addProduct($id){



                    if(Session::get('products')['id']){

                    $product_niz = Session::get('products')['id'];

                                foreach ($product_niz as $item) {

                                    $item != $id ? $a=false : $a=true;

                                        if($a) goto end;

                                    }

                                    if(!$a) {Session::push('products.id', $id);goto end;}

                    } else {

                     Session::push('products.id', $id);


                    }






            end:

            $proizvodi = Session::get('products')['id'];

            $products = Product::findMany($proizvodi);

            if(Session::has('product_'.$id)){

                $amount = 1;

                Cache::increment('amount'.$id,$amount);

                Session::set('product_'.$id,Cache::get('amount'.$id));

                return view('checkout',compact('products'));


            } else {

                Cache::put('amount'.$id,1,10);

                Session::set('product_'.$id,Cache::get('amount'.$id));

                return view('checkout',compact('products'));
            }}
```

When I hit the ADD button on one of my views, the route is called and function addProduct is executed. But it is called on page refresh too and I don't want that. 
How can I prevent function from executing on page refresh ?

Comment: You should use POST instead of GET to create stuff.

Comment: I solved it with PATCH method. You pointed me in right direction. Thabks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change 2 things in your code:

Your form METHOD to **POST**

```
<form method="POST">...</form>
```

And the route method accordingly

```
Route::post('/add/{id}', ['as'=>'addProduct','uses'=>'CartController@addProduct']);
```

Otherwise, everytime you hit the page, you may also hit that controller action.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this in routes

```
Route::patch('/add/{id}', ['as'=>'addProduct','uses'=>'CartController@addProduct']);
```

Added this form

```
    {!! Form::model($product,['method'=>'PATCH','action'=>['CartController@addProduct',$product->id],'files'=>'true']) !!}



            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::submit('ADD',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}

            </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I'm getting alert on refresh, so it's ok.